# parcolumns in \autocite footnotes

Tags: footnotes, parcolumns

I have a thesis chapter that has been compiling perfectly well on one machine, but when I installed and updated MacTex2013 on my new machine, it throws up all kinds of errors. I don't know where the exact problem is, but for some reason formatting inside the square brackets of \autocite commands does not seem to be working any more.

Here is the example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{example_bibliography.bib} 
@article{citethis,
    Author = {Some Guy},
    Date-Added = {2014-05-01 21:09:02 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-05-01 21:10:03 +0000},
    Journal = {JOURNAL: The Journal of Journal Studies},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {99--200},
    Title = {Articles Have Names},
    Volume = {1},
    Year = {2014}}
\end{filecontents} 

%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage [french, latin, german, american]{babel} 

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{example_bibliography.bib}

\usepackage{parcolumns}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
             Ligatures=TeX
             ]{Brill}

\begin{document}

Here is some body text.\autocite[Here is some Lorem Ipsum text in a footnote w/o parcolumns:
\smallskip
{Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.\smallskip
But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness.}%
][100--181]{citethis}


More body text: Here is some Lorem Ipsum text in parcolumns:
\begin{parcolumns}{2}
\colchunk[1]{%
Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. 
}%
\colchunk[2]{%
No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful.
}%
\end{parcolumns}%


%Here is some body text.\autocite[Here is some Lorem Ipsum text in a footnote with parcolumns:
%\begin{parcolumns}{2}
%\colchunk[1]{%
%Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
%}%
%\colchunk[2]{%
%Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?
%}%
%\end{parcolumns}%
%\smallskip%
%][100--181]{citethis}

\end{document}
```

Parcolumns alone sets correctly, as does the autocite, but when I uncomment the last one, which compiles fine on the other machine, I get all kinds of errors, as it seems to think sentences are individual cites, for example:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Neque porro quisquam est' on page 1 undefined on input 
line 57.
```

and a break on:

```
l.57 \colchunk[2]{
                %
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this will be difficult to get working; `parcolumns` does not work out of the box inside `\footcite` or `\parencite` or even `\cite`, so `\autocite` is not even the root problem.  Easy to emulate in the way you want, though: `\usepackage{xparse} \NewDocumentCommand{\myautocite}{oom}{\footnote{#1\par\hfill \cite[#2]{#3}}}`.  (Exact formatting easy to change...)

Comment: That works for \autocite with parcolumns, but I am afraid I do not understand how \autocites works, to extend the change. Can this be made to work with \autocites and also with a \longtable that is in one of the footnotes?

Comment: This would not be easy in the emulated format suggested above if each citation may or may not need `parcolumns` or `longtable`s (due to the inflexible hardcoding).  If you can describe the (range of) typical use-cases you envision, then a better solution will be possible.  `xparse` allows for the creation of pretty elaborate macros full of conditionals.  The biggest problem may be all the different optional arguments that `\autocites` caters to: will you need the functionality of all the following: multiprenote, multipostnote, prenoteN, postnoteN, prenoteN+1, postnoteN+1, etc.?

Comment: I generally only use the prenotes and the postnotes for each individual cite, though I gather it would be better to use the global prenote and postnote for talking about the whole list.

I have temporarily fixed the formatting by installing TexLive 2012, which makes everything set by the desired behaviour (a very significant oversight by me in the above post). Would be more productive for me to submit a comment on the packages suggesting that this would be desirable behaviour? The way it previously worked was both intuitive and produced attractive results for complex footnotes.

Comment: I don't have TL2012 to test anymore, but I am surprised it ever worked since `longtable` and `parcolumns` were last changed in 2004 (incidentally, I recommend the use of the `pdfcolparcolumns` package as a better drop-in replacement for `parcolumns`, but that won't fix the problems). It may well be a useful bug report/feature request to submit for `biblatex`, *especially* if it worked/works with one version and not with another one (it doesn't work with v2.8a).  Anyway, if you have it "fixed" for now, I don't think a hacky workaround is really necessary ... or is it?